# Sum function in the R programming

Tags: r, function

In R , I have a vector like x= 3:100

I want to write function like:

```
sum ( (x/a)^2t)  - 5
```

and get the answer if I choose any value for t .

Example:

```
Func= function ( t ) {
x=c(1:100)
a= min(x)
Sum ( x / a )^2t - 5 
}
```

I don't know if this correct or not.

what about if I want to get the root of the function by secant method. I use `library(NLRoot)` in R. but the codes that I write it is not correct.

```
library(NLRoot)
curve(func, xlim=c(0,3), col='blue', lwd=1.5, lty=2,xlab="x",ylab="f(x)")
```

output is written Error in code.

Comment: 1) Is it `x = 3:100` or `x = 1:100`? 2) In `x=c(1:100)` the call to function `c()` is redundant, remove it. 3) R is case-sensitive and you're missing the multiply op: `sum ( (x / a)^(2*t) ) - 5`.

Comment: yes x= 1:100 . Thanks.

Comment: what about if I want to get the root of the function by secant method. I use library(NLRoot) in R. but the codes that I write it is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a syntax correction

```
Func <- function(t) {
  x <- c(1:100)
  a <- min(x)
  sum((x / a)^(2 * t)) - 5
}
```

and a more compact version might be something like below

```
Func <- function(t, x = 1:100) sum((x / min(x))^(2 * t)) - 5
```

---

To find the root, thanks for comments from @Rui Barradas, we can use `uniroot`, i.e.,

```
> uniroot(Func, interval = c(-5, 5))
$root
[1] -0.5091492

$f.root
[1] -0.0003913713

$iter
[1] 13

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: thanks, what about if I want to get the root of the function by secant method. I use library(NLRoot) in R. but the codes that I write it is not correct.

Comment: @Majid Sorry that I have no idea how to solve the root

Comment: @Majid See my edited answer regarding finding the root